# Collection View Controller no getter method for read from property

Tags: ios, collectionview

I was following a tutorial on using Collection View Controller and I am stuck on final bit.

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                 cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MainMenuItemViewCell *myCell = [collectionView
                                    dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MainMenuItemCell"
                                    forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImage *image;
    int row = [indexPath row];

    image = [UIImage imageNamed:_carImages[row]];

    myCell.imageView.image = image;

    return myCell;
}
```

on line `myCell.imageView.image = image;` I  receive an  error "no getter method for read from property"

Here is MainMenuItemViewCell.h

```
@interface MainMenuItemViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *ImageView;
@end
```

I am sure it is something stupid. I am a newbie in iOS programming so please take it into consideration

Thx

Comment: `ImageView` should be `imageView` (lowercase 'i') in your property declaration

Comment: You should have put that as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ImageView` should be `imageView` (lowercase 'i') in your property declaration.